# onReceive method not working in android

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native push notification module. When I fire notification through google FCM then I want to add key value pare in storage when app is killed or in background. I have written the code but it is not working. I tried to get the key by using `AsyncStorage` and [react-native shared-preferences module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shared-preferences). But always getting null.

**Java code**

```
package com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.helpers.ApplicationBadgeHelper;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class RNPushNotification extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "RNPushNotification";// all logging should use this tag

    private RNPushNotificationHelper mRNPushNotificationHelper;
    private final Random mRandomNumberGenerator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public RNPushNotification(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);

        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);

        Application applicationContext = (Application) reactContext.getApplicationContext();
        mRNPushNotificationHelper = new RNPushNotificationHelper(applicationContext);

        registerNotificationsRegistration();
        registerNotificationsReceiveNotification();
        registerNotificationsRemoteFetch();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "RNPushNotification";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
        final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();

        return constants;
    }

    private void sendEvent(String eventName, Object params) {
        ReactContext reactContext = getReactApplicationContext();

        if (reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
            reactContext
                    .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                    .emit(eventName, params);
        }
    }

    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra("notification")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("notification");
            bundle.putBoolean("foreground", false);
            intent.putExtra("notification", bundle);
            notifyNotification(bundle);
        }
    }

    private void registerNotificationsRegistration() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".RNPushNotificationRegisteredToken");

        getReactApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
                WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
                params.putString("deviceToken", token);
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("key", 100); editor.commit();
                sendEvent("remoteNotificationsRegistered", params);
                Log.e("Notification","registerNotificationsRegistration");
            }
        }, intentFilter);
    }

    private void registerNotificationsReceiveNotification() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".RNPushNotificationReceiveNotification");
        getReactApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                notifyNotification(intent.getBundleExtra("notification"));
                Log.e("Notification","registerNotificationsReceiveNotification");
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("key", 99); editor.commit();
            }
        }, intentFilter);
    }

    private void registerNotificationsRemoteFetch() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".RNPushNotificationRemoteFetch");
        getReactApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("notification");
                String bundleString = convertJSON(bundle);
                WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
                params.putString("dataJSON", bundleString);
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("key", 98); editor.commit();
                sendEvent("remoteFetch", params);
                Log.e("Notification","registerNotificationsRemoteFetch");
            }
        }, intentFilter);
    }

    private void notifyNotification(Bundle bundle) {
        String bundleString = convertJSON(bundle);

        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        params.putString("dataJSON", bundleString);
        sendEvent("remoteNotificationReceived", params);
        Log.e("Notification","notifyNotification");
    }

    private void registerNotificationsReceiveNotificationActions(ReadableArray actions) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        // Add filter for each actions.
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.size(); i++) {
            String action = actions.getString(i);
            intentFilter.addAction(getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "." + action);
        }
        getReactApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("notification");

                // Notify the action.
                notifyNotificationAction(bundle);

                // Dismiss the notification popup.
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                int notificationID = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("id"));
                manager.cancel(notificationID);
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("key", 96); editor.commit();
                Log.e("Notification","registerNotificationsRemoteFetch");

            }
        }, intentFilter);
    }

    private void notifyNotificationAction(Bundle bundle) {
        String bundleString = convertJSON(bundle);

        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        params.putString("dataJSON", bundleString);

        sendEvent("notificationActionReceived", params);
    }

    private String convertJSON(Bundle bundle) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    json.put(key, JSONObject.wrap(bundle.get(key)));
                } else {
                    json.put(key, bundle.get(key));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return json.toString();
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void requestPermissions(String senderID) {
        ReactContext reactContext = getReactApplicationContext();

        Intent GCMService = new Intent(reactContext, RNPushNotificationRegistrationService.class);

        GCMService.putExtra("senderID", senderID);
        reactContext.startService(GCMService);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void presentLocalNotification(ReadableMap details) {
        Bundle bundle = Arguments.toBundle(details);
        // If notification ID is not provided by the user, generate one at random
        if (bundle.getString("id") == null) {
            bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(mRandomNumberGenerator.nextInt()));
        }
        mRNPushNotificationHelper.sendNotification(bundle);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void scheduleLocalNotification(ReadableMap details) {
        Bundle bundle = Arguments.toBundle(details);
        // If notification ID is not provided by the user, generate one at random
        if (bundle.getString("id") == null) {
            bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(mRandomNumberGenerator.nextInt()));
        }
        mRNPushNotificationHelper.sendNotificationScheduled(bundle);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void getInitialNotification(Promise promise) {
        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("notification");
            if (bundle != null) {
                bundle.putBoolean("foreground", false);
                String bundleString = convertJSON(bundle);
                params.putString("dataJSON", bundleString);
            }
        }
        promise.resolve(params);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(int number) {
        ApplicationBadgeHelper.INSTANCE.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(getReactApplicationContext(), number);
    }

    // removed @Override temporarily just to get it working on different versions of RN
    public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    // removed @Override temporarily just to get it working on different versions of RN
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Ignored, required to implement ActivityEventListener for RN 0.33
    }

    @ReactMethod
    /**
     * Cancels all scheduled local notifications, and removes all entries from the notification
     * centre.
     *
     * We're attempting to keep feature parity with the RN iOS implementation in
     * <a href="https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/RCTPushNotificationManager.m#L289">RCTPushNotificationManager</a>.
     *
     * @see <a href="https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html">RN docs</a>
     */
    public void cancelAllLocalNotifications() {
        mRNPushNotificationHelper.cancelAllScheduledNotifications();
        mRNPushNotificationHelper.clearNotifications();
    }

    @ReactMethod
    /**
     * Cancel scheduled notifications, and removes notifications from the notification centre.
     *
     * Note - as we are trying to achieve feature parity with iOS, this method cannot be used
     * to remove specific alerts from the notification centre.
     *
     * @see <a href="https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html">RN docs</a>
     */
    public void cancelLocalNotifications(ReadableMap userInfo) {
        mRNPushNotificationHelper.cancelScheduledNotification(userInfo);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void registerNotificationActions(ReadableArray actions) {
        registerNotificationsReceiveNotificationActions(actions);
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

By share preference module

```
SharedPreferences.getItem("key", function(value){
     console.log(value);
   });
```

By usingAsyncStorage

```
await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending push notifications through FCM panel than onReceive will not be called if your app is in background. You need to send "data message". That is the only message type from which you can create custom notification, or call custom intent. If you cend standard notification from FCM console than OS will automatically create notification, and create intent for it. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) .